# OS pop-up windows are unresponsive on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, bug, dialog

I've been having this issue for many OS versions now, where every other day, all of the OS level dialog windows (sorry I don't know the technical name for them) will become unresponsive after appearing on the screen, e.g., these two windows at the bottom here (I've also included my MacBook info at the top FYI)... [image]

Neither button does anything on these windows and I usually have to reset my computer for them to go away. Sometimes the issue will return immediately, other times it will take a few hours. By the way, the issue doesn't only occur with Fusion360. It happens all the time while using other apps too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same exact issue.

I use the keyboard to navigate these windows (tab, up, down, enter, etc.), although depending on the window it doesn't always work. Should I discover a more desire t or reliable fix, I’ll edit this “workaround” answer with more details.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I’m going to edit this so people that skim it don’t think you’re posting a “me too” only

Comment: This issue is still persisting as of today on Monterey 12.6 although it has gotten a little better. I seem to only get unresponsive windows pertaining to "Legacy System Extension" now; "Parallels International GmbH" in my case...